# Force Truncation on VARCHAR modification?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, alter-table

I would like to cap VARCHAR to 255 on a few columns so that I can add an index.

```
alter table striker modify contacts varchar(255)
```

When I try to run the above command I get

```
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'contacts' at row 331   38.969 sec
```

Is there a way to force truncation of the column so that this command successfully shortens the VARCHAR? I don't care about shortening the data in the column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manually truncate the column at 255 characters:

```
UPDATE striker
SET    contacts = SUBSTR (contacts, 1, 255);
```

Now, that you know that no value is longer than 255 characters, you perform the `alter table` statement you have in the OP safely.

Comment: Just to enforce that a string here indeed begins at position 1, and not at zero (0) as in other languages such as substr in PHP (often coupled with MySQL) - which in this case would shorten the string to 254

Answer (score 0):

Why bother truncating the column?  Just create the index with a length specifier for the column.  Here is an example:

```
create index idx_striker_contacts on striker(contacts(255))
```

You can do this for multiple columns.

Comment: I wanted to add an index to improve query performance. Will a partial index do that?

Comment: @ChrisHall . . . MySQL should use the index under most circumstances (for `=`, `<`, `like`, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, although I found my way here in 2022 with this question and didn't find a satisfying solution. Assuming you are prototyping locally, which the question implies, since these queries may have profound effects on your data, as always - use with caution. Intentionally simplified and straight forward: this should work, assuming you're logged in with root privileges - which seldom should be the case in anything near production, right. This guy sets strict mode etc aside temporarily:

```
SET @tempsql_mode= @@global.sql_mode;
SET @@global.sql_mode= '';
alter table striker modify contacts varchar(255);
SET @@global.sql_mode= @tempsql_mode;
```